# eBay Feed API -> uploadFile script working on local PC but not working on live server

Tags: ebay-api

Here is my script which uploads feed to ebay. The script working on local PC but when I upload to my live server, it does not work.

Here is my code.

```
public function createTask($feedType='FX_LISTING')
    {
        $link = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task";
        //$appConfig = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
        
        //payload
        $payload = json_encode(array("schemaVersion"=>"1.0","feedType"=>"FX_LISTING"));


        //$appConfig['user_token'] = 'mehboob';
        $ch = curl_init($link);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization:Bearer ' . $this->userToken,
            'Accept:application/json',
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_US'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLHEADER_SEPARATE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //scurl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($response, $header_size);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);  

        echo($body);
        curl_close($ch);

        $headers = explode("\r\n", $headers); // The seperator used in the Response Header is CRLF (Aka. \r\n) 

        $headers = array_filter($headers);

        $loc = basename(implode(preg_grep("/^location.*/", $headers)));
      return $loc;


    }
 


    public function uploadFile($taskID, $fName)
    {
          $link = "https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/$taskID/upload_file";
         $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $link,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE(realpath($fName)),'type' => 'form-data'),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->userToken,
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
        'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_US'
        ),
        
        )); 
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        var_dump($response);

        curl_close($curl);

    }
```

Using the code as under:

```
$feedPath = __DIR__ . "/" ."feed.csv";
$taskID= createTask();
$uF = uploadFile($taskID,$feedPath);
```

The above code works fine on my local PC, creating task id and uploading file to ebay. But when I am uploading code on my server, it gets failed.
I confirmed the path to the file on my server is OK.
Also I am using the same version of PHP on my server.

Please see the following response I receives from Server.

```
string(595) "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error rlogid: t6pitaf%60btuf1%3D9vjdpitaf%60btuf1*or3ah%28rbpv6775-1795f5551e5-0x2340 x-ebay-client-tls-version: TLSv1.2 content-type: application/json content-length: 228 date: Wed, 12 May 2021 06:48:18 GMT x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 125 server: ebay-proxy-server x-ebay-pop-id: UFES2-LVSAZ01-api {"errors":[{"errorId":160001,"domain":"API_FEED","subdomain":"Selling","category":"APPLICATION","message":"There was a problem with an eBay internal system or process. Contact eBay Developer Technical Support for assistance."}]}"
```

The error says about "eBay internal error" but I don't think so. its due to some problem in the code.

The documentation to the above eBay service is as under:
[eBay Feed File - uploadFile documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/feed/resources/task/methods/uploadFile)

Your cooperation in this context will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    This code is in C# - RestClient
    
    createTask
    ==========
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer v^1.1#i^1****** YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN *********Ql3QYER3BQAAA==");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_GB");
    var body = @"{
    " + "\n" +
    @"  ""schemaVersion"": ""1149"",
    " + "\n" +
    @"  ""feedType"": ""LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS""
    " + "\n" +
    @"}";
    request.AddParameter("application/json", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
    Response:
    location:https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027
```

task-12-1127376027 is your TaskID

```
    uploadFile
    ==========
test.xml file
--------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <SKU>test-1111</SKU>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  </InventoryStatus>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <SKU>test-2222</SKU>
    <Quantity>20</Quantity>
  </InventoryStatus>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>



upload code
-----------
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027/upload_file");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer v^1.1#i^1****** YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN *********Ql3QYER3BQAAA==");
    request.AddHeader("X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID", "EBAY_GB");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    request.AddParameter("fileName", "test.xml");
    request.AddFile("file", "F:/test.xml");
    request.AddParameter("type", "form-data");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
    Response: "StatusCode: OK, Content-Type: , Content-Length: 0)"
    
    getTask
    ========
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1235290549");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer v^1.1#i^1****** YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN *********Ql3QYER3BQAAA==");
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    
    Response:
    {
        "taskId": "task-12-1127376027",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS",
        "creationDate": "2022-02-09T11:39:50.000Z",
        "completionDate": "2022-02-09T11:50:34.000Z",
        "uploadSummary": {
            "successCount": 0,
            "failureCount": 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TASK
============
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
  "schemaVersion": "1149",
  "feedType": "LMS_REVISE_INVENTORY_STATUS"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^*****YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE****py9v3J3ALc5rcFAAA',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_GB'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

UPLOAD FILE
===========

test.xml file
-------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <SKU>test-1111</SKU>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
  </InventoryStatus>
  <InventoryStatus>
    <SKU>test-2222</SKU>
    <Quantity>20</Quantity>
  </InventoryStatus>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>


<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027/upload_file',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('fileName' => 'test.xml','file'=> new CURLFILE('/F:/test.xml'),'type' => 'form-data'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^*****YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE****py9v3J3ALc5rcFAAA',
    'X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_GB',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;


GETTASK
=======
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.ebay.com/sell/feed/v1/task/task-12-1127376027',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^*****YOUR USER ACCESS TOKEN HERE****py9v3J3ALc5rcFAAA',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```